# I have some problem with my homework to connect to mongodb using mongoose

Tags: mongodb

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")
const app = require("../app")
const dotenv = require("dotenv");
dotenv.config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000
const DB_PATH = process.env.DB_CONNECTION_URL


const db = mongoose
  .connect(DB_PATH, {
    useCreateIndex: true,
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Database connection successful");
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`Server running. Use our API on port: ${PORT}`);
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
    process.exit(1);
  });

module.exports = db
```

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdUSB.png)

> MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
> at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (/Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:694:11)
> at /Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:351:10
> at /Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
> at new Promise ()
> at promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/helpers/promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
> at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (/Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:1149:10)
> at Mongoose.connect (/Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/node_modules/mongoose/lib/index.js:350:20)
> at Object. (/Volumes/Mac - Data/GitHub/hw7/nodejs-homework2-rest-api/bin/server.js:11:4)
> at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
> at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
> at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
> at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
> at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
> at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
> [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Comment: can you show your .env file?

Comment: also can you print `console.log(process.env.DATABASE_URL);`

Comment: thanks, it was wrong variable name written in the .env file DB_URL change on DB_CONNECTION_URL